# start with the default state upon rendering the component for the first time ! where no mood has been selected yet

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

[image]
I'm new to reactJs , I have been struggling to try to find out how to manage to get the functionality of the design attached in the picture, (the emotions rendering just fine) but still cannot make it false when the user enter that screen for the first time and no mood is selected.
using Hooks how can I implement such a feature  ??

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import {Row, Col} from "react-bootstrap";

import Button from "../../elements/buttons/Button";
import Icon from "../../elements/icons/Icon";
import "./FacialReactions.scss";
import $ from 'jquery';




 export default function Emoji() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // code...
        const feedbackC = document.querySelector(".feedback");
    const addComment = document.querySelector(".feedback_comment");
    const ratings = document.querySelector(".feedback_ratings");
    const rating = document.querySelectorAll(".feedback_rating");
    const notice = document.querySelector(".feedback_notice");
    const noticeContainer = document.querySelector(".feedback-n");
    
     ratings.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        const clicked = e.target.closest(".feedback_rating");
        console.log(clicked);
        if (!clicked) return;
    
        rating.forEach((r) => r.classList.remove("rating_active"));
        clicked.classList.add("rating_active");
    
        const data = clicked.dataset.rate;
        const rateEmoji = clicked.textContent.split(" ")[0];
        const rateText = clicked.textContent.split(" ")[1];
        console.log(rateEmoji);
    
        noticeContainer.innerHTML = "";
        const html = `<section class="feedback_notice">
                    <p> ${
                        data < 3
                            ? `Sorry to heard that ${rateEmoji}! Thank you for the feedback `
                            : `${rateText}! Thank you ${rateEmoji}`
                    } </p>
                
        
                </section>`;
    
        noticeContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    });
    
    
      });

    

    return (
     <>
        <div class="feedback">
        <div className="containerText">
            <div className="text" style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <span className="first" > How you were feeling </span>&nbsp;
                <span className="second" style={{color: '#FFA196'}}> before you </span>&nbsp;


            </div>
            <span className="third" style={{color: '#FFA196',justifyContent:'center'}}>you used the vibrator ?</span>

        </div>

        <div class="feedback_ratings">
            <span class="feedback_rating" data-rate="1"> <Icon icon="mood-vbad" variant="horizontal" /> </span>
            <span class="feedback_rating" data-rate="2"> <Icon icon="mood-bad" variant="horizontal" /></span>
            <span class="feedback_rating" data-rate="3"> <Icon icon="mood-neutral" variant="horizontal" /></span>
            <span class="feedback_rating" data-rate="4">  <Icon icon="mood-good" variant="horizontal" /></span>
            <span class="feedback_rating" data-rate="5">  <Icon icon="mood-vgood" variant="horizontal" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback-n">

        </div>

    </div>
     </>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ReactJS you can directly bind your events to your HTML tags, You do not need to create an event listener manually.

This is quite easy to implement with ReactJS

I have provided you simple and beginner-friendly solution with help of reactJS hook useState below

But I can clearly grasp you don't have a basic understanding of ReactJS concepts and best practices, I strongly recommend you to learn ReactJS basics [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#react-for-beginners)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

   export default function Emoji() {

       const [mood , setMood] = useState(null) //initial state is null, so no mood will be selected by default when component loads
       const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false)


 function selected(e) {
   //we run this function on listening to onClick event from the DOM
   setMood(e.target.value) //updating the value of state

         if (mood != null){ 
            setShowButton(true)
           }
    }
 
 return (
       <div>
        <div className="Feedback_rating">
           <button onClick={selected} value="1">Vbad</button>
           <button onClick={selected} value="2">bad</button>
           <button onClick={selected} value="3">neutral</button>
           <button onClick={selected} value="4">good</button>
           <button onClick={selected} value="5">Vgood</button>
        </div>
         
        //using ternary operator to conditionally render markup on the DOM
        {(showButton) ? <button>Next</button> : null}

       </div>
    )
}
```

If This code does not make any sense to you, you need to start learning about react.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Oh ,thanks for your reply. however, this is not what I want to implement actually!

would you rather give me such a reusable component to figure out my own way to get that functionality !?

Comment: I would be happy to help but I do not understand what kind of reusable component you want, please give me more description here or You can email me at kulrajchavda@gmail.com if you want further help.